# Pagination with Room not able to merge Flow<PagingData<Model>> with other flows properly

Tags: android, android-paging-3, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-stateflow

I'm trying to use `Paging 3` library to get `Flow<PagingData<Scan>>` from `Room`, then check if item was selected or not in the recyclerview so I'm mapping this class to another class called `ScanMapper`. For achieving this mapping, whenever user marked an item as selected, I updated `Map` inside a `MutableStateFlow<Map<Int, State>>`. Here the `Map` looks up an `Index(Int)` to get the `State`, `State` is just an `enum` class to represent State `UNINITIALISED`, `USELECTED` and `SELECTED`.

I am setting the value of the Map to a `StateFlow<Map<Int,State>>`. The problem is, I am trying to combine the `Flow<PagingData<Scan>>` with the `StateFlow<Map<Int,State>>` in order to also pass the `State` as a parameter to the `ScanMapper` class since this `State` is taken from the `StateFlow<Map<Int,State>>` and is not a part of the original `Scan` class. But the `PagingDataAdapter` seems to always get the `State UNINITIALISED` despite when I'm marking item as selected on item click using the `markSelected(scanId: Int)` function.

Kindly tell me what I am missing here.

**UPDATE**

I was able to achieve the functionality that i wanted by using a `Flow<List<Scan>>` and removing the usage of `Paging 3` library using a recycler adapter with `DiffUtils`. Though this is not the actual solution since it eliminated the `pagination using paging 3` library, but the following changes allowed me to perform item selection:

**Updated Dao**

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM scan ORDER BY timeOfStorage DESC")
fun getAllScansList(): Flow<List<Scan>>
```

**Updated Function in ViewModel**

```
fun getData(context: Context): Flow<List<ScanMapper>> {

    val dao = ScanDatabase.invoke(context).getScanDao()

    return combine(
        dao.getAllScansList(),
        myMap
    ) { scan, stateMap ->
        scan.map {
            it.toScanMapper(stateMap[it.id] ?: State.UNKNOWN)
        }
    }.flatMapLatest {
        flow {
            emit(it)
        }
    }
}
```

**Updated fragment code**

```
mainViewModel.getData(requireContext()).collect {

    adapter.asyncListDiffer.submitList(it as MutableList)
}
```

**Original Question**

**My Scan class:**

```
@Entity(tableName = "scan")
@Parcelize
data class Scan (
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    var id: Int = 0,
    val name: String,
    val recognisedText: String,
    val timeOfStorage: Long,
    val filename: String
): Parcelable {

}
```

**My ScanMapper class:**

```
data class ScanMapper(
    val id: Int,
    val name: String,
    val recognisedText: String,
    val timeOfStorage: Long,
    val filename: String,
    val isSelected: State
)

enum class State{
    UNINITIALISED,
    SELECTED,
    UNSELECTED,
    UNKNOWN
}
```

**Converter for Scan to ScanMapper and vice-versa**

```
fun ScanMapper.mapToScan() =
Scan(
    id = id,
    name = name,
    recognisedText = recognisedText,
    timeOfStorage = timeOfStorage,
    filename = filename
)

fun Scan.toScanMapper(isSelected: State) =
ScanMapper(
    id = id,
    name = name,
    recognisedText = recognisedText,
    timeOfStorage = timeOfStorage,
    filename = filename,
    isSelected = isSelected
)
```

**My PagingSource inside Dao**

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM scan ORDER BY timeOfStorage DESC")
fun getAllScans(): PagingSource<Int,Scan>

@Query("SELECT id FROM scan")
fun getAllIds(): List<Int>
```

**Getting flow using getScansFlow()**

```
fun getScansFlow(context: Context): Flow<PagingData<Scan>> {

    val scanDao = ScanDatabase.invoke(context).getScanDao()

    return Pager(
        config = PagingConfig(
            pageSize = 10,
            maxSize = 30,
            enablePlaceholders = false
        ),
        pagingSourceFactory = { scanDao.getAllScans() }
    ).flow.cachedIn(viewModelScope)

}
```

**Initialising the Map for ids present in Room**

```
fun initList() =
       viewModelScope.launch {

    var idList: List<Int> = listOf()

    withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {

        val task = async {
            return@async ScanDatabase.invoke(context).getScanDao().getAllIds()
        }
        idList = task.await()
    }

    val map = _myMap.value.toMutableMap()

    for (id in idList) {
        map[id] = State.UNINITIALISED
    }

    _myMap.value = map

}
```

**Function in ViewModel that gets the flow and combines them**

```
    fun getScansSyncFlow(context: Context) {

    viewModelScope.launch {

        combine(
            getScansFlow(context),
            myMap
        ) { scan, stateMap ->
            scan.map {
                it.toScanMapper(stateMap[it.id] ?: State.UNKNOWN)
            }
        }.collect{
           _myFlow.emit(it) 
        }
    }
  }
```

`myFlow` is a `StateFlow<PagingData<ScanMapper>?>`.

This is how I am updating the `Map` when an item gets selected by the user in recyclerview.

```
fun markSelected(scanId: Int) {

    val map = _myMap.value.toMutableMap()
    map[scanId] = State.SELECTED
    _myMap.value = map
}
```

Then, I am collecting this `myFlow` in my `fragment` like this:

```
lifecycleScope.launchWhenStarted {

mainViewModel.getScansSyncFlow(requireContext())

mainViewModel.myFlow.collect { data ->

      data?.let {
        
          adapter.submitData(it)
       }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The immediate issue I see is that you are using collect instead of collectLatest. Since submitData does not return, you will never receive updates from your Flow.

```
mainViewModel.myFlow.collectLatest {
  adapter.submitData(it)
}
```

Comment: Hello , may i ask about an issue that i'm facing with paging library 3 , and caching with room db , data shows properly , it does save data with room but only the first values that shows , if for example i have 40 values and showing 10 each time , it does only show the first 10 values , any reason why sir , thank you ?

Comment: Can you share your project / code or ask a proper question on SO? Happy to help.

Comment: Thank you , i have created this topic , can you check it out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67559551/paging-library-storing-only-first-fetched-values-in-room-database