# Paging library storing only first fetched values in room database

Tags: android, kotlin, paging, android-paging-library

I have an application where i implemented paging library 3 to fetch data from api and paginate it , it works fine fetching data , the next implementation was to store the fetched data in room database , i have created the remotemediator class and wrote the code to store data , but the issue is that it stores only values of first page ( for example in my case im using the movie db api , each page fetched has 20 movies , and there are many pages ) , in my case it only saves the first 20 movies , even when i scroll , it is not storing more data , i have implemented the same exact code but seems to be the case , i faced it in an older project and now this one , i need some help , thank you in advance.

- Movies Dao

```
 @Dao
interface MoviesDao {

    @Query("SELECT * FROM movieTable ORDER BY id")
     fun getMovies() : PagingSource<Int,Result>


    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    suspend fun insertMovies(result: List<Result>)


    @Query("DELETE FROM movieTable")
    suspend fun clearMovies()


}
```

- RemoteKeys Dao

```
@Dao
interface RemoteKeysDao {

    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    suspend fun insertAll(remoteKey: List<RemoteKeys>)

    @Query("SELECT * FROM remote_keys WHERE movieId = :movieId")
    suspend fun remoteKeysRepoId(movieId : Long): RemoteKeys?

    @Query("DELETE FROM remote_keys")
    suspend fun clearRemoteKeys()


}
```

- RemoteMediator Class

```
private  var MOVIES_API_STARTING_PAGE_INDEX = 1
@ExperimentalPagingApi
class MoviesMediator(
    private var authResponse: AuthResponse,
    private  var movieDatabase: MovieDatabase
) : RemoteMediator<Int,Result>() {

    override suspend fun load(loadType: LoadType, state: PagingState<Int, Result>): MediatorResult {
        val page = when (loadType) {
            LoadType.REFRESH -> {
                val remoteKeys = getRemoteKeyClosestToCurrentPosition(state)
                remoteKeys?.nextKey?.minus(1) ?: MOVIES_API_STARTING_PAGE_INDEX
            }
            LoadType.PREPEND -> {
                val remoteKeys = getRemoteKeyForFirstItem(state)
                val prevKey = remoteKeys?.prevKey
                if (prevKey == null) {
                    return MediatorResult.Success(endOfPaginationReached = remoteKeys != null)
                }
                prevKey
            }
            LoadType.APPEND -> {
                val remoteKeys = getRemoteKeyForLastItem(state)
                val nextKey = remoteKeys?.nextKey
                if (nextKey == null) {
                    return MediatorResult.Success(endOfPaginationReached = remoteKeys != null)
                }
                nextKey
            }
        }
        try {
            val response = authResponse.getMovies(Constants.API_KEY, Constants.LANGUAGE, page).results


            val endOfPagination = response.isEmpty()
            movieDatabase.withTransaction {
                // clear all tables in the database
                if (loadType == LoadType.REFRESH) {
                    movieDatabase.remoteKeysDao().clearRemoteKeys()
                    movieDatabase.MovieDao().clearMovies()
                }
                val prevKey = if (page == MOVIES_API_STARTING_PAGE_INDEX) null else page - 1
                val nextKey = if (endOfPagination) null else page + 1

                val keys = response.map {
                    RemoteKeys(movieId = it.movieID, prevKey = prevKey, nextKey = nextKey)
                }
                movieDatabase.remoteKeysDao().insertAll(keys)
                movieDatabase.MovieDao().insertMovies(response)
            }
            return MediatorResult.Success(endOfPaginationReached = endOfPagination)
        } catch (ex: Exception) {
            return MediatorResult.Error(ex)
        }
    }

    private suspend fun getRemoteKeyForFirstItem(state: PagingState<Int, Result>): RemoteKeys? {
        // Get the last page that was retrieved, that contained items.
        // From that last page, get the last item
        return state.pages.firstOrNull() { it.data.isNotEmpty() }?.data?.firstOrNull()
            ?.let { movieId ->
                // Get the remote keys of the last item retrieved
                movieDatabase.remoteKeysDao().remoteKeysRepoId(movieId.movieID)
            }
    }
    private suspend fun getRemoteKeyClosestToCurrentPosition(state: PagingState<Int, Result>): RemoteKeys? {
        // The paging library is trying to load data after the anchor position
        // Get the item closest to the anchor position
        return state.anchorPosition?.let { position ->
            state.closestItemToPosition(position)?.movieID?.let { movieId ->
                movieDatabase.remoteKeysDao().remoteKeysRepoId(movieId = movieId)
            }
        }
    }

    private suspend fun getRemoteKeyForLastItem(state: PagingState<Int, Result>): RemoteKeys? {
        // Get the last page that was retrieved, that contained items.
        // From that last page, get the last item
        return state.pages.lastOrNull() { it.data.isNotEmpty() }?.data?.lastOrNull()
                ?.let { repo ->
                    // Get the remote keys of the last item retrieved
                    movieDatabase.remoteKeysDao().remoteKeysRepoId(movieId = repo.movieID)
                }
    }

}
```

- Passing RemoteMediator to paging data

```
    val dataFlow : kotlinx.coroutines.flow.Flow<PagingData<Result>> =
        Pager(getPagingConfig(),
        remoteMediator = MoviesMediator(authResponse,movieDatabase)){
            MoviePagingSource(authResponse)
        }.flow
            .cachedIn(viewModelScope)
```

- Showing data in MainActivity

```
 @ExperimentalPagingApi
    private fun setUpAdapterOnline(){
        moviesAdapter = MoviesAdapter()
        lifecycleScope.launchWhenStarted {
            moviesModel.dataFlow.collectLatest {
                moviesAdapter.submitData(it)
            }
        }

        binding.recycler.adapter = moviesAdapter
        binding.recycler.adapter =  moviesAdapter.withLoadStateHeaderAndFooter(
            header = LoadingStateAdapter { moviesAdapter.retry() },
            footer = LoadingStateAdapter { moviesAdapter.retry() }
        )
    }
```

Comment: Could you also share how you use the `Flow<PagingData<Result>>` ? Are you using `collectLatest` to observe it? Also, are you getting calls to `RemoteMediator` for `APPEND` / `PREPEND` at all?

Comment: Yeah i'm using collectLatest , for append and prepend , i think they are only called once , i'm not much familiar with paging library 3 but i have put a log where i push data into room in the append part , called first time only ( i mean when first 20 movies are loade )

Comment: I noticed you have two Pagers, one for offline and one for online which seems incorrect to me. Everything in Paging is driven by PagingSource, so you don't need both. RemoteMediator is basically a callback - if you want to use offline data, you can simply attempt the network fetch on remote refresh and only clear + insert if it succeeds.

Comment: If you can share how you are mixing multiple / using the `Flow<PagingData>` here, I can try to help more, but it's not really enough information as it is.

Comment: Actually I also just noticed in your "online" version with RemoteMediator, your `pagingSourceFactory` is also different. What does `MoviePagingSource()` look like? You should be using the one provided from Room since you are inserting into Room and using that to drive Paging.

Comment: i got it now , so i have to use just the same call that fetchs data and also within that call i added the remotemediator callback , but i m not sure if i ve seen refresh remote code in the codelabs , do you please have any template or code on how to do that , because you re right , im fetching data from netwok and database in different , and you said they shoul be in the same code block

Comment: actually MoviePagingSource() is the main call which gets data from api call , and the offlineDataFlow() is function where i get the save data from room but as you said that's not correct and i should implement remote refresh which i don't really know how , any example code to implement that , thank you .

Comment: Your `RemoteMediator` should do the network fetches and update DB via Room. Then you should use PagingSource from Room to drive Paging (which automatically observes for data changes made by RemoteMediator and invalidates to notify paging of updates).

Both our codelab (https://developer.android.com/codelabs/android-paging#14) and our github sample (https://github.com/android/architecture-components-samples/blob/main/PagingWithNetworkSample/app/src/main/java/com/android/example/paging/pagingwithnetwork/reddit/repository/inDb/PageKeyedRemoteMediator.kt) has some good examples of RemoteMediator

Comment: I have removed the offline function wich retreives the data from db and i did as you said  , i m only using one function which combines both , api call + remoteMediator callback ,  i have changed some code , can you please check it out again and tell me how is it possible to call the saved data from room when there is no internet ( trigger data from local cache ) thank you

Comment: i found out that page  ( from load type is not incrementing at all ) , that's why only first page is stored , any reason why please , im checking th codelabs over an over but coulnt figure out

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**

I tried using [this](https://newsapi.org/) `NewsApi` instead of [this](https://unsplash.com/documentation#search-photos) `Unsplash Api`. Even though the `NewsApi` provides the `per_page` as a query parameter, still I faced similar problem where only `first 2` pages load and after that on debugging it shows that the `APPEND` block inside the `Load` method is getting called over and over and the value assigned to `page` is always 2. Hence the `next pages` aren't getting fetched at all.

**ORIGINAL ANSWER**

@dlam is right, you need to follow the [Single source of truth](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/guide#truth) principle here, and only request data from the `Paging Source` inside `MoviesDao`. I did not find the exact solution for your problem, but I do have some findings to share.

I would say that I debugged the `Remote Mediator` in the sample codelab [here](https://github.com/googlecodelabs/android-paging/tree/step13-19_network_and_database) and I found that it actually increments the `page` as you scroll. However, when debugging your code from the github link you sent me, the value of `page` never increments and the `APPEND` block inside `MoviesMediator` is executed over and over, even when not scrolling. I tried to find the reason and the only thing I can come up with is the `Api` that you are using. I tried the same feature, saving from `network` to `database` but using the `Unsplash Api` and I was able to view all the pages when offline too (not just one page unlike your case).

I'm not sure if it is the `per_page` parameter that the codelab also passed as an `argument` inside the `Network/Api Service` Interface. In my case, the `Unsplash Api` also allowed to pass `per_page` as an argument.

Here I am attaching a [link to my github repository](https://github.com/Mehul-Bisht/Paging_3-Demo). Try comparing the results and feel free to ask any more doubts.

Comment: there could be an issue with the api yeah but with paging library 2  i could save multiple pages , so i'm not really sure why

Comment: The project I linked is able to save multiple pages as well with Paging 3. Take a look :)