# Is there a better way to update recyclerview in paging3 with room?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room, android-jetpack, android-paging

in my fragment

```
            lifecycleScope.launch {
                viewModel.capture().collectLatest {
                    adapter.submitData(it)
                }
            }
```

Now  when I update the item in `Recyclerview`.

```
repository.update(bean)
```

```
db.withTransaction {
    db.dao().update(bean)
    service.update(requestBody)
}
```

Because I use paging3 with remoteMediator, like:
In dao:

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM content ORDER BY ... ")
fun getAll(): PagingSource<Int,Content>
```

In viewmodel:

```
fun capture() = repository.captureYiMaFlow()
```

In repository:

```
fun capture()=
    Pager(
        config = PagingConfig(pageSize = 6), 
        remoteMediator = SettingMediator(service, db)) {    
            db.dao().getAll()    
        }.flow
```

The room will auto change the item data in recyclerview.So the data in database will be update.
Becaue I call the `service.update(requestBody)` so the data in server will be update.

---

### But the UI  of recyclerview doesn't change. I need to close the fragment and open again, then the UI will change.(note that the data of recyclerview have been change. For example:the data of first item of recyclerview is `100`, and I update it to `1000`,then when I click the item ,the data is `1000`, But the UI data doesn't change, it is `100`...

Although I can use `adapter.notifyDataSetChange（）` to update the UI，I think there is muat some other ways to finish it

Comment: as much data is provided and assuming that you implemented the `Remote Mediator` as mentioned in the docs, it does look fine especially with the `collectLatest` operator that I was missing and cause me an issue here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67495592/pagination-with-room-not-able-to-merge-flowpagingdatamodel-with-other-flows.

I can't really think of any possible solutions by looking at this information, maybe add a github link to your project?

Comment: @mehulbisht I have solve this problem......  But I also have another problem...

Comment: so what is the issue this time? :)

Comment: I put it on the answer:
if I change the order of the two line code, the result is different.

`adapter.submitData(it)
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`

Comment: well, can you show what the `submitData` actually does? Is it a method of `DIffUtils` or a custom method that you created?

Comment: Is it a method of DIffUtils, it isn't a custom method . I just call the submitData in PagingAdapter

Comment: `DiffUtils` doesn't require you to call `notifyDataSetChanged` explicitly. Does it work only when you call `notifyDataSetChanged` and not when `DiffUtils` method `submitData` is called?

Comment: I suspect your DiffUtil.ItemCallback is failing to detect the change.

Answer (score 0):

In fragment.  Add `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`,like:
Change

```
lifecycleScope.launch {
    viewModel.capture().collectLatest {
        adapter.submitData(it)
    }
}
```

to

```
lifecycleScope.launch {
    viewModel.capture().collectLatest {
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
        adapter.submitData(it)
    }
}
```

The above code can solve the problem.

---

However,if I change the order of those two lines of code, it won't work as expected

it means if I use

```
lifecycleScope.launch {
    viewModel.capture().collectLatest {
        adapter.submitData(it)
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
    }
}
```

It won't work as expected.....